# Why can't I modify module.exports? Why does my browser complain after no problems from `npm run build`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

Why doesn't the browser let me do:

**Getters.js**

```
let Getters = {}
Getters.foo = function(){ return 1; } 
Getters.bar = function(){ return 2; }
module.exports = Getters;
```

But after `npm run build` and `serve -s build -l 4000`, I get the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
    at Module.<anonymous> (Getters.js:954)
```

Is there an easy way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported any module with es6 import statement? If yes, try updating to common js module. Don't mix up es6 and commonJS import statements.

```
es6
import a from '/a.js';

commonJS
const a  = require('/a.js');
```

Comment: The code works fine on the development server, just stops working when I build it.